# SDL is drawing the rectangle in some frames but a weird sliced rectangle in others

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sdl-2

I'm trying to draw a basic rectangle using the SDL render API:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

bool init() {
    bool success = true;
    
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL couldn't init! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else {
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (gWindow == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Window couldn't be created! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            success = false;
        }
        else {
            gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if (gRenderer == NULL) {
                std::cout << "Renderer couldn't be created! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError();
                success = false;
            }
            else {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

bool loadMedia() {
    bool success = true;
    return success;
}

void close() {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    if (!init()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to init!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        SDL_Event e; 
        bool quit = false; 
        
        while(!quit) { 
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ){ 
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) quit = true; 
            }

            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
            SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer); 
                
            SDL_Rect fillRect = {SCREEN_WIDTH / 4, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 };
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
            SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &fillRect);

            SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
        }
    }

    close();

    return 0;
}
```

In some frames SDL will draw the rectangle correctly, but in others the rectangle will draw outside the window and be super stretched with weird slices:

[image: Weird Slices]

Whenever I drag the window around, it draws the rectangle correctly, but once I stop it will start behaving as I mentioned above.

Honestly, I'm not sure what could be causing it given the code I have.

Comment: Is it running in docker?

Comment: SDL version?  OS & windowing system?

Comment: I'm using SDL2 and whatever is the latest version, I downloaded it the other day. OS is Ubuntu running on my Windows machine using WSL.

Comment: Please add `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: I see a similar issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/1130#issuecomment-1816183336), it was resolved by updating nvidia drivers, updating the packages, and restarting WSL using `wsl --shutdown`. Can you try this?

Comment: Another option is to simply not use WSL2. You'll need to make an actual Windows executable sooner or later to distribute your app to others. If you prefer your current compiler (GCC or Clang) and/or various Linux utilities, there's [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075). Or get Visual Studio.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry about that. Doing what you suggested in your second comment about updating packages fixed my issue, thank you.